# Linq Group By - select a single record in each group into typed result

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

The below is query is similar to what I am trying to achieve but simplified. 
In my actual code, I have four table joins and trying to get a result which has latest version in it. I have C# version I got very close to, but could not create a Vb version with type result set

**C# version**
This query generates appropriate sql I wanted, but could not select columns I needed.

```
var query= from user in Customers join adrs in CustomerAddress
             on user.Id equals adrs.CustId
             group user by adrs.CustId into g
             select g.OrderByDescending(x=>x.adrs.Version).First();
```

**VB Version**
This query is failing in order by and calling the First is generating lousy sql in the back

```
dim query= from user in Customers Join adrs in CustomerAddress _
              on user.Id Equals adrs.CustId _
           Group By custId=adrs.CustId Into g = Group _
           Order By adrs.version Descending _
           Let latestAddress=g.First() _
           Select new ResultObject() with _
           { _
           .AddressId=latestAddress.adrs.Id, _
           .Street=latestAddress.adrs.Street _
               }

dim results=query.ToList()
```

-- Update

I am looking for SQL similar to this, which is generated by the C# query above with the exception that I want to choose the column names.

```
SELECT [t3].[test], [t3].[ID], [t3].[RequestQueueId], [t3].[CI_RequestType], [t3].[CI_Division], [t3].[CI_Company], 
FROM (
    SELECT [t0].[RequestQueueId]
    FROM [RequestHeader] AS [t0]
    GROUP BY [t0].[RequestQueueId]
    ) AS [t1]
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP (1) 1 AS [test], [t2].[ID], [t2].[RequestQueueId], [t2].[CI_RequestType], [t2].[CI_Division], [t2].[CI_Company], 
    FROM [RequestHeader] AS [t2]
    WHERE [t1].[RequestQueueId] = [t2].[RequestQueueId]
    ORDER BY [t2].[Version] DESC
    ) AS [t3]
ORDER BY [t3].[Version] DESC
```

Comment: Can you post the equivalent TSQL you want to achieve

Comment: @Raymund, I have updated question with desired sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this will solve your issue

```
var query =
from customeraddress in db.CustomerAddresses
join customers in db.Customers on new { CustId = customeraddress.CustId } equals new { CustId = customers.Id }
join LatestVersion in
    (
        (from customeraddress_1 in db.CustomerAddresses
            group customeraddress_1 by new
            {
                customeraddress_1.CustId
            } into g
            select new
            {
                CustId = (System.Int32)g.Key.CustId,
                MaxVersion = (System.Int32)g.Max(p => p.Version)
            }))
        on new { customeraddress.CustId, customeraddress.Version }
    equals new { CustId = Convert.ToInt32(LatestVersion.CustId), Version = Convert.ToInt32(LatestVersion.MaxVersion) }
select new
{
    Id = (System.Int32)customers.Id,
    customers.Field1,
    customers.Field2,
    customeraddress.Field3,
    customeraddress.Field4,
    Version = (System.Int32)customeraddress.Version
};
var results = query.ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

For starters, you could just make your VB version identical to your c# version if you liked the sql so much, since the columns you want will be available on the object that the c# version returns.  I'm not too good with query syntax, but I think it's something like:

```
Dim query = From user In Customers Join adrs In CustomerAddress _
    On user.Id Equals adrs.CustId _
    Group user By adrs.CustId Into g _ 
    Select g.OrderByDescending(Function(x) x.adrs.Version).First()
```

However, one possible fluent version would be something like:

**C#**

```
    var query = Customers
    .Join(
     CustomerAddress,
     x => x.Id,
     x => x.CustId,
     (o,i) => i
    ).GroupBy(x => x.CustId)
    .SelectMany(x => x
     .OrderByDescending(y => y.version)
     .First()
    ).Select(x => new ResultObject() {
     AddressId = x.Id,
     Street = x.Street
    });
```

**VB**

```
    Dim query = Customers _
    .Join( _
     CustomerAddress, _
     Function(x) x.Id, _
     Function(x) x.CustId, _
     Function(o,i) i _
    ).GroupBy(Function(x) x.CustId) _
    .SelectMany(Function(x) x _
     .OrderByDescending(Function(y) y.version) _
     .First() _
    ).Select(Function(x) New ResultObject() With { _
     .AddressId = x.Id, _
     .Street = x.Street _
    })
```

NOTE:  The above code is untested, but I hope that it helps!